# Which programs will receive auto updates on Ubunutu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

I am trying to determine **which programs will receive auto updates** on my **Ubunutu 16.04LTS** PC.

I have installed these programs via the software center:

- filezilla
- gimp
- synaptic
- unetbootin
- virtualbox-qt

I have installed these from command line by adding a ppa and installed using apt:

- google-chrome-stable
- sublime-text

When I use Synaptic under the status tab and `Installed (manually)` if I sort by non-Ubuntu installed I can see all the programs listed above.

If I then click `Installed (upgradeable)` the only non-Ubuntu installed package is `google-chrome-stable`.

1. Why is `google-chrome-stable` the only one listed as upgradeable?
2. How does Synaptic determine a package as 'upgradeable'?
3. I assume the software center updates will infact be updated as I think I have seen this in the software center itself, but would that happen through apt-get update?

I am trying to understand if programs installed using these methods are auto updated:

- Downloaded via Ubuntu Software Center
- Via command line by adding a PPA and installing
- By downloading a .deb and installing (e.g. Dropbox)

I am correct in thinking that `apt-get update` will update any software which was installed using an apt command originally?

So if it was a .deb it is installed via dkpg and therefore apt-get wont apply, if so is there anyway to automatically update these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `google-chrome-stable` is the only outdated package you have in your system (which is not installed by Ubuntu) at that time.
2. A package is listed at `Installed (upgradeable)` means that there is a newer package available and you can upgrade the package. If you had the filter of `non-Ubuntu installed`, it will only show outdated packages YOU installed.
3. Ubuntu Software Center will run `apt-get update` every time (I think) and detect whether you have software updates or not. Running `apt-get update` will only update your list of packages, it will not tell you anything about whether you have software updates or not. `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade packages, which is the same as updating packages from Ubuntu Software Center.
4. Packages downloaded via Ubuntu Software Center will be auto-updated because it acts the same as installing with `apt-get`.
5. Packages installed via command line by adding a PPA and installing will also be auto-updated because when running `apt-get update`, `apt-get` will also update the list of packages from the PPA.
6. Packages installed by downloading a .deb and installing via `dpkg -i` may get auto-updated depending on whether the repository is added into the list of apt (i.e. `/etc/apt/sources.list`). Some packages like `google-chrome-stable` will do so, so they will get updated.

Edit: Ubuntu has a cronjob to run `apt-get update` everytime you boot up, so all lists of packages will be updated when you boot your computer.